# Grails 3 hibernateDatastore stratup error after migrating from Grails 2

Tags: grails, dependency-management, grails3

I am upgrading to Grails 3.3.1 from a Grails 2.4 app. 
Things seemed to be going slow but OK until I stumbled into this problem when trying to run the app:

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core


Configuring Spring Security Shiro ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Shiro

2017-12-19 18:51:43.400 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsCacheFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#3238926e' of type [grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter] while setting bean property 'filter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3238926e': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setUrlMappingsHandlerMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'urlMappingsHandlerMapping': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setWebRequestInterceptors' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'openSessionInViewInterceptor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting bean property 'hibernateDatastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2017-12-19 18:51:43.492 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

  grailsCacheFilter
      ↓
  (inner bean)#3238926e
      ↓
  urlMappingsHandlerMapping
      ↓
  openSessionInViewInterceptor
┌─────┐
|  hibernateDatastore
└─────┘
```

Hibernate and Shiro version in the build gradle:

```
// hibernate 
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:6.0.13"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.10.Final"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.10.Final"
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-shiro:3.0.1'
```

Is this a common error people are running into?

Will I have to go through my dependences one by one to see if one of them is causing this?

Comment: Do you have overloaded setters?  That seems to be something that bit me, even from Grails 3.2 to 3.3.

E.g.   class Something {  Integer myVal;   setMyVal(String s) { myVal = s as Integer; } }

Comment: Hi Robert, not that I know of but that's a good thing to be aware of for future coding

Comment: It's common problem upgrading from 2 to 3. But it may caused by different reasons.
First of all run "gradle dependencies"  it will probably show some dependencies conflicts after upgrade. If nothing, try to setup logback to log org.springframework.beans package from trace level to find in which bean do you have cycle injection.

Comment: @EvgenySmirnov - thanks for the advice; I see a library is still using hibernate 3.6  `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final -> 5.1.10.Final (*)`  . I am guessing this is the problem?

Comment: Found the issue in my code.  Changing the logback config to `root(DEBUG, ['STDOUT'])` is very useful during the migration